# .splice() method not working in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, splice

Whenever I use the `splice` method in Javascript like so:

```
Array.prototype.mymethod = function() {
  return this[num].splice();
}
```

It returns an error in my tests saying that `splice()` is not a method in Javascript. The test only contains an array consisting of `['a', 'b', 'c']`, however it's not working when the prototype I'm using tries to `splice()` the array. Can't seem to figure out what's going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.splice()` splices the array

`this[num].splice()` tries to splice the element at index num which is a string and doesnt have a splice method

Comment: Also you are referencing a outside variable inside a prototype method. Doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling splice on an element of the array, not on the array itself.